If <button> tag is an inline element, why it behaves like a block element?
Why does the button behave like a block element if it is an inline element?
I mean, it gets padding, margin, width, and height.


.btn-3 {
  background-color: #8000ff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5em;
}
<button class="btn-3">button 1</button>



